# Ubuntu Wifi not working

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I am trying to learn using ubuntu. I installed ubuntu on my Sony Vaio. The installation was successful. But I couldn't connect to the wifi. When connected to the ethernet it works fine. How do I connect to the wifi?

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && \
chmod +x wireless_script && \
./wireless_script
```

I used the above command and got the following output.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 11 Apr 2015 10:37 BST +0100

Booted last: 11 Apr 2015 10:20 BST +0100

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e071]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

0e:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:0123]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:0543 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: nfc0: NFC
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

bcma                   52320  0 

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.12  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3e07:71ff:fe60:3d57/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:14968 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11523 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:14991355 (14.9 MB)  TX bytes:1234560 (1.2 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search Home

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.12
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wi-Fi connection 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Wi-Fi connection 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=sky
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/London (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[bcma]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
srcversion:     D52E980A55E0AC3C372382C
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        7B:E2:A7:20:0F:17:F0:0C:A0:11:F7:0E:5A:87:4C:37:E3:E0:F6:BE
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

Now what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

That wifi card should work with

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Or you can download from a mirror site http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/download